# Connection strings depending on environment

Tags: asp.net, web-config, connection-string

I am currently working on a web application using Visual Studio 2015, asp.net mvc 5. I would like to define some connection strings but only for my 'Dev' environment, right now they are defined in Web.config but I'd like them to be only in Web.Dev.config.

I added the following in Web.Dev.config:

```
<add xdt:Locator="Match(name)" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes(connectionString)" name="SModel" connectionString="same connection string as in web.config" />

<add xdt:Locator="Match(name)" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes(connectionString)" name="CDev" connectionString="same connection string as in web.config"  />
```

But when I run my application in the Dev environment, it's telling me that the connection strings can't be find.

Comment: Have you got two connection strings named SModel and CDev in the original Web.config file? If you don't then these transforms won't match anything (and so can't set the attributes on anything). 

This might provide some help (see the section on preview transforms): https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/web-config-transformations

Comment: Make sure you add the entire xml tree up to the nodes you are transforming. You cannot simply place the <add nodes by themselves.